Why android is triggering double splash screen even after using SplashScreen API?
I've implemented the SplashScreen API in my jetpack compose application. As it is obious my application is single-activity application. But when i upload the app to play console it's warning that on android 12 and above double SplashScreen is being displayed. Please note that there is no loading other than splash screen either there is no other splash screen. I've implemented the SplashScreen API only. I did some research onn internet and i found that the practice that i've been gone thorugh is correct. I've follow Google official documentation for that. I've implemented the splashScreen like this exactly :
https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/splash-screen-api-with-jetpack-compose-9001c561b9c8
Please provide any proven solutions. I would like to tell you that i cannot use <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> as its cauing the app a delayed restart also its removing the splashScreen completely.
Thank you

Hello! Same problem here, did you find a solution? I can only think that after setContent I compose my theme and inside the app:
  Theme {
    App()
  }
}```
